How to remove user from Jenkins
It seems that many users, resembling Git users, have been automatically created in the Jenkins user interface. Despite not enabling "Create new accounts based on author/committer's email" in the Git plugin, these users cannot be manually deleted.
jenkins version is 2.426.3
Is there a way to remove them?

I assume you see them in the People view? Are you sure those are user accounts rather than a "people view" that lists and combines both accounts and "seen people"?

Thank you for your response.
I'd like to understand why these accounts are "automatically" appearing (they weren't created by an administrator for people to use) and why they cannot be deleted.

You did not answer whether you are basing your assumptions on the "People" view. I pointed out that what you see and think are accounts may not be accounts. (I don't know myself. I find Jenkins unclear about it.)
